# How to use ternary operator in Vue binding

Tags: vue.js

```
<label class="switch"> 
<input type="checkbox"  v-on:change="updateRequiredData(list.input_permission_id,selected, selected == 'Applicant' ? list.status : selected =='Guaranter' ? list.guaranter_required : selected ='Reference' ? list.guaranter_required)"  v-bind:checked="list.status =='1'" >    
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I have to update value of check-box according to select condition like if i select applicant it shows applicant check box, when i select 'Applicant' the function should update list.update 
If i select guaranter it should take list.guaranter_required and update

Comment: How is this question related to php and codeigniter?

Comment: it's not a good practice to put the logic into your template , you could use computed property

Comment: please provide your data object code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have way too much going on in your template, which makes it easier to make mistakes in your logic. Also, with the number of cases you're checking, using the ternary operator quickly becomes very unwieldy. Try something like this instead:

```
<label class="switch"> 
    <input type="checkbox"
        v-on:change="updateRequiredData(list.input_permission_id, selected, this.selectionResult)"
        v-bind:checked="list.status =='1'"
    >    
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

// In your computed properties or methods
// Which one will depend on what scope selected and list are available at in your component)
selectionResult: function() {
    switch (selected) {
        case 'Applicant': return list.status;
        case 'Guaranter':
        case 'Reference':
            return list.guaranter_required;
    }
}
```